# Select column to update based on value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

What I am trying to do is reduce the time needed to aggregate data by producing a roll-up table of sorts. When I insert a record, an after insert trigger is fired which will update the correct row. I would update all of the columns of the roll-up table if I need to, but since there are 25 columns in the table and each insert will only update 2 of them, I would rather be able to dynamically select the columns to update. My current update statement in the after insert trigger looks similar to this:

```
update peek_at_chu.organization_data_state_log odsl
inner join  (   select
                    lookUpID as org_data_lookup,
                    i.interval_id,
                    peek_at_chu.Get_Time_Durration_In_Interval1('s', new.start_time, new.end_time, i.start_time, i.end_time) as time_in_int,
                    new.phone_state_id
                from
                    (peek_at_chu.interval_info i
                     join peek_at_chu.interval_step int_s on i.interval_step_id = int_s.interval_step_id)) as usl on odsl.org_date_lookup_id = usl.org_data_lookup
                                                                                                                 and odsl.interval_id = usl.interval_id
set
    total_seconds = total_seconds + usl.time_in_int,
    case new.phone_state_id
        when 2 then
            available_seconds = available_seconds + time_in_int
    end;
```

In this, lookUpID is a variable previously declared in the trigger. The field that will dictate which field of the roll-up table to update is `new.phone_state_id`. The `phone_state_id`'s are not consistent, that is some numbers are skipped in this table, so an update based on column number is out the window unless I create a mapping.

The `case` option throws an error but I am hoping to use something similar to that instead of 25 `if` statements if I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update all the columns, but use a conditional to determine whether to give it a new value or keep the old value:

```
set total_seconds = total_seconds + usl.time_in_int,
    available_seconds = IF(new.phone_state_id = 2, available_seconds + time_in_int, available_seconds)
```

Repeat the pattern in the last line for all the other columns that need to be updated conditionally.

Comment: I figured that was what I needed to do, just wondering if there was a better way.